# Need help building a class that displays a list activity from a http input

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm not sure what the extent of the help I need but I thought I would ask, even if I just get pointed in the right direction.

I have a basic layout with text box and and submit button.

I have a class called `hellodatabase` with sends a string to a php file which retunes a result to text view.

What I need to do is send the string to the `hellodatabase` class and then display the result.

Below is a class that I have found in a tutorial that I have been using for my database connection.

Any help creating this class will be great or just pointing me in the right direction.

```
package example.hellodatabase;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HelloDatabase extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.  
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
    rootLayout.addView(txt);  
    setContentView(rootLayout);  

    // Set the text and call the connect function.  
    txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
  //call the method to run the data retreival
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/1.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","beans"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Get an output to the screen
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}    

}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/) for reference. You can see creating table, adding data, editing, delete in ListView; this will be easy for you to understand.

Comment: While you Iterate the value add all values to ArrayList then by using Iterator convert it to String Array.. Either then you use Custom Adapter and inflate a list view and set the text in it..or use any Adapter as you like.. list_fname.add(jo.getString("Value")); string[] VALUE_fname = new String[list_fname.size()];
Iterator<String> it = list_fname.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
fn++;
VALUE_fname[fn] = it.next().toString();
} set this String array to adapter

Comment: Venkatesh im sure you understand what i need to do but i dont understand much of how it all works at the moment, if you can talk me through building this class it will help me loads.

Comment: A link-only answer was supplied below, [pointing here](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/). It may be deleted by the Review Queue, so I am preserving it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

First that all, you need to extend ListActivity, a ListActivity must contain a ListView (wich contains the ListView rows) and an Adapter that receives the data and build the layout within the ListView.

You have the data into a Json String, so, each row will hold a Json string entry.

The most important thing is the Adapter, the adapter is the responsible about the ListView creation. You must declare the Adapter as an Inner Class to your ListActivity in order to perform the operations mentioned above. The structure will be this: (on pseudocode)

```
MyActivity extends ListActivity{
   ListView listView;

   MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataBean>{
     public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Object> objects) {
       //here you initialize all your stuff and helper things
     }
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //this is the most important method cause this will make the layout for a single row.
   }
}
```

Here a complete example:

```
public class PeopleList extends ListActivity {

    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String data = getServerData();
        //split the data and pass to the adapter like a List<String>
        listAdapter = new PeopleListAdapter(this, R.id.listItemFirstLine, data);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        getListView().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_new_search_activity_1));
        getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    }

    class PeopleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        /**
        * This method will construct the ArrayAdapter and add the objects String List to its inner List.
        */
        public PeopleListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        /**
        * Here we inflate a xml layout and put into a view (convertView)
        * We set the necessary data into a static class (for performance reasons)
        * Setting the itemHolder like a tag of the 'convertView' will put the ItemViewHolder inner views
        * (TextView title, TextView description and ImageView icon) as the convertView childs views.
        *   Param: position will return the position for wich we are constructing the view
        *          convertView, the view that we have to build and return 
        *          parent, is the ListView
        */
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            itemHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
            if(convertView == null){
                //inflate the xml layout and assign like child view of the parent parameter.
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_propiedades, parent, false);
                convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
            }
            itemHolder.title = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemFirstLine));
            itemHolder.description = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemSecondLine));
            itemHolder.operationIcon = ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.operationIcon));
            itemHolder.title.setText( getItem(position) );
            itemHolder.description.setText( getItem(position) );
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    static class ItemViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView operationIcon;
    }

}

Later is the xml layout that corresponds to each row: R.layout.lista_propiedades

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/operationIcon"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/pin_home_any" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemFirstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:textColor="#FF333333"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/listItemSecondLine"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@id/listItemFirstLine"
        android:textColor="#FF666666"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sit amet dui nunc. Suspendisse scelerisque quam non massa mollis eleifend. Ut dapibus fermentum leo, ac mattis enim fringilla eu. Praesent non lorem ut orci facilisis pulvinar. Fusce pretium lorem non erat interdum quis sodales massa dapibus. Maecenas varius varius elementum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas sem magna, rutrum eget aliquet vitae, lacinia sit amet purus. Integer odio magna, euismod in luctus ut, ullamcorper at nisl. Phasellus ullamcorper, nisl a posuere tristique, augue justo tincidunt velit, eget placerat ligula sem eget augue. Morbi tempus, felis vel mattis pharetra, lacus massa suscipit tortor, vel laoreet dui nulla quis nulla. Praesent scelerisque fermentum neque ut vulputate. Pellentesque in urna sit amet lorem auctor porta a non libero. Nam ac sem ac dui ornare interdum. Aliquam scelerisque, nibh vitae interdum scelerisque, metus arcu iaculis nisi, id sagittis orci augue consectetur purus. " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I suggest you to watch this video: [The World of ListView](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70).